# angular: pass additional data with form submit

Tags: angularjs

At the moment i am using below code and it is working fine.

```
  $scope.processForm = function($scope.formData) {
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : 'process.php',
            data    : $.param($scope.formData),  // pass in data as strings
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        })
```

Now i have one small requirement. I need to pass user id(**uid**) along with the form data.
In Jquery it is quite simple but I am new to angular and don't have much experience.

Any advise how i can pass the additional data in Angular.

Thanks

Comment: You can encapsulate your formData with your uid parameter togheter in an object expl : `var allData={'formData': $scope.formData, 'uid': $scope.uid}`, and then pass in the allData Object to your post method `data : allData`

Comment: formdata is empty. I don't know why.

Comment: Try this :
1-Remove `headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }`
2-in your process.php:
`$postContent= file_get_contents("php://input");
$req= json_decode($postContent);
$formData= $req->formData;
$uid= $req->uid;`

Comment: i tried above but formData is empty.  $formData= $req->formData;  i can see uid but formData is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encapsulate your formData with your uid parameter togheter in an object expl :

`var allData={'formData': $scope.formData, 'uid': $scope.uid}`

And then pass in the allData Object to your post method data : **allData**.

If you encounter any problem getting data in you process.php (undefined data for example), you should let Angular pass data with content type application/json (default behavior of angularjs) and in your `process.php` you do like this :

```
$postContent= file_get_contents("php://input"); 
$req= json_decode($postContent); 
$formData= $req->formData; 
$uid= $req->uid;
```

Note that it will be great if you test with some static values first ( 'uid' : 2 ) to make sure that it works fine

Comment: i tried above but formData is empty.  $formData= $req->formData;  i can see uid but formData is empty.

Comment: Show me your form view (angular)

Answer (score 0):

you can send an object (associative array in php ) in $http data parameter:

```
$scope.processForm = function($scope.formData) {
    console.log($scope.formData);
    $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : 'process.php',
        data    : {'data': $scope.formData,'userid':userid}, // no need to use $.param, even never see it in angular
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
    })
```

see https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-the-angularjs-way  for details on how to get data in php side

Comment: formdata is empty.

Comment: how can i access the data in php. Post is not working.

Comment: the $http in javascript client side, it send the data to your php page who have to handle it. how did you use $scope.processForm() ?  see https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-the-angularjs-way